# Discrepancies in Results from Pysolar

Tags: python, astronomy

I have recently downloaded and installed the PySolar module and would like to use it to calculate sun position (azimuth and altitude).

The problem I am having is that the results calculated do not match the results calculated by the NOAA Solar calculator http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/azel.html

For example. Using the PySol

```
>>> import datetime, solar
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2007,12,21,9,0,0,0)
>>> lat = 41.5
>>> long = -111.5
>>> solar.GetAltitude(lat, long, d)
-63.0267096801
>>solar.GetAzimuth(lat, long, d)
-235.44406245
```

Using the NOAA model The Altitude is calculated at 0.7 and Azimuth is calculated at 237.64.

Therefore there is a discrepancy between the two values. To summarise:

- Pysolar is calculating Altitude at -63.03 and NOAA is calculating it at 0.7
- Pysolar is calculating Azimuth at -235.44 and NOAA is calculating it at 237.64

If you have any suggestions what I am doing wrong or how I can calculate the correct altitude and azimuth for a given location, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datetime.datetime has no tzinfo value so will give you the GMT time which is about 7 hours off from the local time.  The other factor could well be that NOAA used DMS rather than decimal lat/long so you need to remember to input 41,30,0 and -111,30,0 for the values.

N.B. You might find it instructive to try [PyEphrem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) for this sort of calculation as I find that the documentation is clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my reputation wasn't high enough to post an image but I made sure I entered the latitude and longitude in the correct format. Regarding the time zone I set the  offset value on the NOAA to zero to match solpy. I thought that by doing this would give the same result. Do you know how I would go about entering time zone info to my argument? Thanks very much

Comment: To use a timezone you need at create your own tzinfo class.

Answer (score -1):

Change -111 to +111 and your results might be better.
Going west is positive.